# What happens if a contestant's phone turns off?

Tags: mirai-nikki

I was rewatching *Mirai Nikki* and saw Episode 15, and it got me thinking. Is it a requirement for your phone to be always on?

We already know that 'Future Diaries' are, in other words, your future. So if the phone breaks you have no future which means in short that ***you die***.

So my question is: what happens for example if you decide to put your phone into shutdown mode? Do you still die?

Also how exactly are their phones powered? **PS: Magic does not count.**

<sub>I will accept Manga answers as I do not think it was explained in the anime. Also I have not read the manga so I am not sure. I will also accept answers with a bit of opinion as long as it is a good answer with some sort of canon. :)</sub>

Comment: Maybe it isn't possible to turn it off because it is powered with the force of the big Deus Ex Machina :o

Comment: The phone is your life, you break it you die. 

You lose it, you better find it. 

I watched that whole anime relatively recently and I never saw any mention of chargers or battery life. 

My guess is that since it is direcrlt tied to your life force it never turns off unless you die.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think the requirement is *strictly* for the phone to always be on but rather that it shouldn't get damaged. The phone is meant to be a reflection of the user, like a piece of their soul. So if it's damaged, the user is also affected. It probably doesn't hurt to just casually turn it off since it doesn't harm the phone. Although, it would be a BIG disadvantage, lol! I would guess the power would work the same too.